# ReferenceError: "X" is not defined when used with-in promises JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, asynchronous, promise

I am having trouble in **using promises** in javascript 
Actually I am trying to **start the second function when the first function ends** as the first function performs some operations on data and in the second function this data will be used further
Here is the first function which loads the data and this data later to be used in the second function

```
    update_users: function() {

        fetch(this.users_url)
        .then(
            function(response) {
                return response.json();
            }
        )
        .then(
            (data) => {
                this.data.users = data;
                let event = new CustomEvent("modelUpdated", {detail: this});
                window.dispatchEvent(event);
            }
        );    
    },
```

Here is the second function

```
  get_user: function(userid) {


        var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

              // do a thing, possibly async, then…

             console.log("Reached");

                update_users();

                  if ( true) {
                    resolve("Stuff worked!");
                  }
                  else {
                    reject(Error("It broke"));
                  }
                });


            promise.then(function(result) {

                let check = 0;
                for(let i = 0; i < this.data.users.length;  i++)
                    {
                        console.log(".." + i);
                        if(this.data.users[i].id == userid)
                        {
                            console.log("This was the id we were talking about.");
                            console.log(this.data.users[i]);
                            check = check + 1;
                            return this.data.users[i];
                        }
                    }

                if (check = 0)
                {
                    return null;
                }

              console.log(result); // "Stuff worked!"
            }, function(err) {
              console.log(err); // Error: "It broke"
            });

    },
```

Here is the error

```
ReferenceError: update_users is not defined
    at model.js:250
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.get_user (model.js:244)
    at main.js:40
```

Comment: Perhaps it should be `this.update_users()`? Just guessing ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I would also make `update_users` **return** the `fetch` promise, ie `return fetch(...`. Then you can wait for it to complete when calling `update_users`

Comment: `update_users()` is apparently a method or property of some object.  To call it, you will need to reference that object.

Comment: There is no need to return anything as the function updates the dataSet with in the class. But still I tried to return fetch(....  but it didn't work. Secondly yes you are right i tried this.udate_users but it didn't work

Comment: If you tried `this.update_users()` and the error message stayed the same, then you changed the wrong code or you didn't actually change anything